# SQL xxx.myTable what are the xxx called

Tags: sql

In my company we use lots of SQL tables and they are all named like `MasterData.Client` I know that `Client` is the tablename but what would be `MasterData` in this case?

Additionally I would like to know how to access it like this:

```sql
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 Where  TABLE_NAME = 'Client'
                 And    TABLE_??? = 'MasterData'))
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Table Exists'
END
```

Comment: Maybe a silly comment... but could `MaterData` be the database name?

Answer (score 0):

It is called a schema and is acsessable using `TABLE_SCHEMA`

so the statement would look like this

```sql
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 Where  TABLE_NAME = 'Client'
                 And    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MasterData'))
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Table Exists'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

It's little bit like a Namespace, called schema, often equal to a database user. A relational Database runs on a server ServerA with an instance MyInstance and a schema MySchema with your client-table inside containing a column called columnA. This does mean, the path is: ServerA.MyInstance.MySchema.client.columnA

Data that changes slowly, with low volume and is used to describe objects like customers, is often master data. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_data | https://open-ls.de/en/master-data-definition/). The difference is for example an offer or an order. So probably it does mean, that your Schema MasterData is used to encapsulate all tables containing master data.